# Can SignalR be used with ANY database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, push-notification, signalr, informix

I need to implement push technology in my application. I need to display data on the web page as it gets inserted in the database in real time.

I am using ASP.NET MVC with IBM Informix as backend database. I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use SignalR with Informix?

Does SignalR have any dependency on the backend database? Or could it be used with any database?

Comment: SignalR is **not** a database change state reporter => not related to any database

Comment: @SirRufo I need to show data on my webpage as it gets inserted in the database table. The database not MS Sql . It is IBM Informix. Can I achieve what I want with SignalR and with informix at the backend? Since I am going to be showing data from database in real time I think it is a little related to database used in the backend

Comment: With SignalR you can publish informations to the clients. It does not care what kind of information and if that information is related to any database. Like a TextBox which can display Text and did not care if that text comes from a dtatabase

Comment: @SirRufo but then how does server know when there is a new record in the database?

Comment: @SirRufo I don't know if this has any basis but someone told me that there is a service that is run by the backend database which sends a signal whenever there is a new record in the table and this service is probably not a feature of IBM informix.

Comment: Who is really writing the data into the database? The server? Then the server will know when

Comment: By server I mean the MVC web Appliaction A . Lets assume that the table which i have could be updated by some other application B. I do not have control over B. How would A know when there is new data in database?

Comment: Then you should work on your concept.

Comment: @SirRufo does that mean it won't work in this scenerio? If a third party application writes data in my table . I can not have real time updates on my page?

Comment: Sir Rufo is trying to tell you that your database and your SignalR hub are two totally separate things. You CAN use it to notify changes to your clients, but nevertheless you need to get signals from your DB to your web application in the first place.

Comment: Use always a controlled environment. Build a data service and let any application talk to that data service. The data service itself uses whatever database and manage reading, writing and notification. It does not matter if the application is third party or a web application, but let them only talk to the data service.

Comment: There is a Java service that writes data to the table. I am not sure how I can find out when that Java service has written any data.

Answer (score 1):

Signal R is a system for real time (ish) communication over an HTTP connection and your database is for data storage. The two are solutions to completely separate problems, and there is no dependency between them. You can write code to link up these two parts of your application.

Comment: Suppose I have a windows service which is responsible for writing new records to the databse table. How can my MVC application find out when I have new data in the table? How can I link up these two parts? Windows service and the MVC web application?

Comment: Your windows service and MVC application can talk using a variety of communications methods. If theyre both on the server you could use named pipes, and if theyre running in the same process, you could just use shared data. The point is, the communication at this level has nothing to do with your database.

Comment: Can you please help me out on how I can make the two talk to each other? The MVC application and Windows service both may or may not be  present on the same server.I don't know where to start.

Comment: This isnt a code writing service, i have an employer who pays me for that kind of thing ;) You have your question, try and do some research on the subject and come back with some specific questions. Ive just put 'how to make a windows service and mvc site talk to each other' into google and the top result is basically the answer to your question.

Comment: I obviously did not ask you or anybody to write down the code. I said I do not know where to get started. What article etc should I read. I just asked for directions not the actual code.  Thanks for the help anyways.